# React Native - How to separate modules in files for native and web?

Tags: react-native, react-native-web

I have some files shared between a React Native (Android & iOS) project & a [React Native Web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web) project.

Some files have the `*.web.js` extension in order to tell webpack (used for react-native-web) to give them priority over other js files in a folder.

I need to exclude those files from compiling in a react-native project.

Answer (score 2):

To define a module which have different implementations and dependencies according to the platform, it should be in a folder with the following architecture:

```
Module/
|-index.js
|-Module.web.js  // web only
|-Module.native.js  // iOS & Android
|-Module.ios.js // iOS only
|-Module.android.js // Android only
```

index.js

```
export {default} from "Module" // import it without extension
```

Then just import it, letting react-native taking care of the plateform

```
import Module from "path/to/Module" // path to Module folder
```

### Extension summary

[image]